# ISSET function to prevent image file overwrites?

Tags: php, mysql

Im setting up a website like gumtree (uni project). I'm implementing the ability for users to be able to edit their listed items. I'm having trouble with the image part. If the user does not want to change the image when updating other rows, the ran function is overwriting the image with random numbers. I have attached a picture of the code.

I want the user to be able to update things like the product name and price without the image being overwritten by random numbers each time they press the update button.

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadimg']['name'])){
$ran = rand(0,1000000);
$filename = $_FILES['uploadimg']['name'];
$filename = $ran.$filename;
$filetmp = $_FILES['uploadimg']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['uploadimg']['type'];
move_uploaded_file($filetmp, "../dbimages/".$filename);

$updateimg = "UPDATE elmtree SET path='$filename' WHERE itemid='$id'";
    $imageupdate = $conn -> query($updateimg);

}
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **A screenshot can’t be searched for or run as code.**

Comment: A hundred times better. Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Instead of using random numbers, why not something like a [`sha256` hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)? That's going to be identical for any given file no matter how many times it's uploaded.

Comment: The code you've provided will literally 99.9999% of the time do nothing but change the image path (the other 0.0001% being when the current `rand()` happens to match the existing `rand()`). What would be an example of a database column -- other than `path` -- that you _would_ want to change?

Comment: I dont want to change anything other than the image, which works fine with that code. The problem is when the user updates their profile on the webpage and hits the update button, if they did not select a new image to upload, their current picture gets deleted from the database and replaced with a number string generated by the rand. I want to stop this from happening